# Add/Delete Table Rows with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am using this html to display my table. I am looping through data to show multiple rows.

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>Item</th>
       <th>Qty</th>
       <th>Price</th>
       <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <?php  $srno=1;
            for ($x=0; $x < count($quotes[0]->workOrderLineItem); $x++ ) {?> 
               <tr>
               <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="detail[]" value="<?php echo $quotes[0]->workOrderLineItem[$x];?>" required=""</td>
               <td width="10%"><input type="number" name="qty[]" value="<?php echo $quotes[0]->qty[$x];?>" required=""</td>
               <td width="15%"><input type="number" name="price[]" value="<?php echo preg_replace("/[\$,]/", '', $quotes[0]->priceArray[$x]); ?>" required=""</td>
            <td width="12%"><div class="inline"><input type="button" id="addButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="Add"/></div><div class="inline"><input type="button" id="deleteButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="Delete"/></div>
           </tr>
          <?php } ?>

          </tbody>
         </table>
```

I am then using this script to add and delete rows

```
$(function(){
$("#addButton").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").clone(true).appendTo("#myTable");
});

$("#deleteButton").click(function(){
    var x = $('#myTable tr').length;
    if(x == 2){

    } else {
         $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    }

});
```

});

This works fine whenever I have a single table row, but when I have multiple rows the additional row "add" and "delete" buttons do not work. Only the first row buttons work. What is the best way to accomplish being able to delete and add rows from the additional rows?

Comment: The problem here is that you are creating multiple table row having same id for the add/delete button. Instead create rows with add/delete button with same class name and then you can use the class selector to bind the click event.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you. I am using the id in the script. How would I go about making the change you suggested?

Comment: remove the id from the td

`<td width="12%"><div class="inline"><input type="button" class="addButton btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="Add"/></div><div class="inline"><input type="button" class="deleteButton btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="Delete"/></div>`

And then change the click selector to $(".addButton") and $(".deleteButton") respectively

Comment: happy to help.. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the id from the td

```
<td width="12%"><div class="inline"><input type="button" class="addButton btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="Add"/></div><div class="inline"><input type="button" class="deleteButton btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="Delete"/></div>
```

And then change the click selector to $(".addButton") and $(".deleteButton") respectivel

Answer (score 0):

can you give me the content of the $quotes var to reproduce your problem in my local environment ?

Thanks, this is the code you should be using, I just made some changes in the $quote var

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>Item</th>
       <th>Qty</th>
       <th>Price</th>
       <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <?php  
       $quotes = [];
       $quotes[] = ['workOrderLineItem' => ["Color Change","Printed Wrap"], 'qty' => [3,2], 'price' => [267, 784] ];
       $srno=1;
            for ($x=0; $x < count($quotes[0]['workOrderLineItem']); $x++ ) {?> 
               <tr>
               <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="detail[]" value="<?php echo $quotes[0]['workOrderLineItem'][$x];?>" required=""</td>
               <td width="10%"><input type="number" name="qty[]" value="<?php echo $quotes[0]['qty'][$x];?>" required=""</td>
               <td width="15%"><input type="number" name="price[]" value="<?php echo preg_replace("/[\$,]/", '', $quotes[0]['price'][$x]); ?>" required=""</td>
            <td width="12%"><div class="inline"><input type="button" name="addButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="Add"/></div><div class="inline"><input type="button" name="deleteButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="Delete"/></div>
           </tr>
          <?php } ?>

          </tbody>
         </table>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                      $("input[name='addButton']").on('click', function(){
                        $newElement = $(this).closest("tr").clone(true);

                      $("#myTable").append($newElement);
            });

            $("input[name='deleteButton']").click(function(){
                      var x = $('#myTable tr').length;
                      if(x == 2){

                      } else {
                          $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                      }

            });
        });
         </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `workOrderLineItem["Color Change","Printed Wrap"], qty[3,2], price[267, 784]` Let me know if you need anything else